# calling plt.plot() shrinks pygame window

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygame

I have this example code:

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')

################## Globals ######################

FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('Cambria', 20)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600, 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])

################ Functions ######################
def draw():
    pygame.event.pump()
    screen.fill((200,200,200))

    text = 'TEST'
    msg = FONT.render(text,True,(0,0,0))
    text_width,text_height = FONT.size(text)
    screen.blit(msg,( (SCREEN_WIDTH-text_width)//2, (SCREEN_HEIGHT-text_height)//2 ))

    # update
    pygame.display.update()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main pygame loop
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    x = np.linspace(0,10,200)
                    y = np.sin(x)
                    plt.plot(x,y)
                    plt.savefig('plot.pdf')
        draw()
        CLOCK.tick(60)
```

When I start the program it looks like this:
[image]

But as soon as I hit SPACE (and therefor call `plt.plot()`) the window shrinks like this:
[image]

Can some one explain why this is happening and maybe how to fix it.

Comment: I don't know. What does that mean / how do I find out if it is?

Comment: Is your monitor scaled? (System settings, e.g. 125%, 150%, 200%)

Comment: Anyway you'r mixing pygame and matplotlib. When you mix different frameworks, the behavior is always undefined and OS dependent. You shouldn't do something like that.

Comment: Yes my monitor is scaled 150%

Comment: So the problem is likely related to that. Either there is a bug in one of these modules or pygame and matplotlib are not working correctly with each other. Why should they? They are developed independently of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix frameworks, mixing frameworks always means some kind of undefined behavior. The frameworks may interact poorly or completely conflict with one another. Getting it to work on your system doesn't mean it will work on another system or with a different version of any of the frameworks.
The particular problem is related to the DPI scale of the monitor. Either there is a bug in one of these modules or pygame and matplotlib do not work correctly with each other. Why should they? They are developed independently of each other.